# Format for proposing a new algorithmic project?

Tags: project-planning

I am working for an organization that is still new to implementing data science projects. I have an idea for a data spider/algorithm project that will require various pieces of code as well as datasets that I will need to gain access to.

I know that this is something that I should just start doing instead of proposing, but unless I come up with a formal document, the org might see it as a "waste of time". So are there any generally accepted formats and/or project templates for proposing a new data science effort?

**To be clear:** I am looking for something that I can present to management and be able to "sell" them on a new data science project idea. So the template I'm looking for isn't necessarily too technical, it's more high-level than that.

Answer (score 1):

There you go [cookiecutter](https://drivendata.github.io/cookiecutter-data-science/) template. I use this, with all the necessary modifications. Each project can be really versatile in Data Science. Nonetheless, I would agree that is a general standard.

Comment: Great resource, thank you! However, I was looking for something more that I can present to management. Like, "this is the project, these are the algorithms, this s the data I will need . . ." stuff like that. Note that I'm still upvoting you because that was a great link, definitely something I need too.

Comment: If I understand correctly, more like a presentation? For a managerial audience.

Comment: That's exactly right. I have edited my OP to clear up this point.

Comment: Tbh, nothing pops to my mind, from my experience following good presentation tips, like avoiding the death by powerpoint and providing as vivid plots as possible does the trick.

Comment: Having some thoughts now, I would use UML tools like draw.io to make entity links of the Data flow and its processing. I remember I had searched some time before on the web similarly, if there is any standard of like a subkind of UML which does this but I wasn't able to find any.